# Why is geth not synced after over a month?

Tags: go-ethereum

I've been trying to sync geth for a month and it still has not caught up. Why?

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.24-stable
Git Commit: cc05b050df5f88e80bb26aaf6d2f339c49c2d702
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.15.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 11618426,
  highestBlock: 11618501,
  knownStates: 793738222,
  pulledStates: 793551086,
  startingBlock: 11550009
}
```

- Running with systemctl using `/usr/bin/geth --http --ws --cache 4096`
- Hardware: NUC 10 i7, 16GB RAM, 2TB SSD. Found here: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0842WCPFR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0842WCPFR)
- Port `30303` is forwarded.
- 50 peers are connected when I check `admin.peers`
- Pulling 3000 - 8000 new states per minute (only ~10M / day)
- Installed using these instructions: https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-eth/guide-or-how-to-setup-a-validator-on-eth2-mainnet#install-from-the-repository

Recent logs:

```
Jan 09 04:35:31 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:35:31.569] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.278ms     number=11618478 hash="133e38…a19af5"
Jan 09 04:35:34 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:35:34.934] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.783ms     number=11618479 hash="bf9e50…899c4b"
Jan 09 04:35:35 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:35:35.530] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0    itemSize=197.83KiB throttle=332
Jan 09 04:35:54 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:35:54.877] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="2.272µs"   processed=793518299 pending=193869 trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:36:00 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:00.242] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.205ms     number=11618480 hash="a6a0ee…dae5d1"
Jan 09 04:36:12 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:12.959] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.139ms     number=11618481 hash="e9a615…d7f5fc"
Jan 09 04:36:13 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:13.779] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="3.553µs"   processed=793518683 pending=194302 trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:36:19 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:19.900] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="1.454µs"   processed=793519067 pending=194728 trieretry=4    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:36:22 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:22.551] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.900ms     number=11618482 hash="59cd5e…9ed360"
Jan 09 04:36:25 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:25.834] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.109ms     number=11618483 hash="9bded9…76bb24"
Jan 09 04:36:39 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:36:39.755] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="40.497µs"  processed=793519451 pending=195149 trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:37:07 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:07.030] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="3.106µs"   processed=793519835 pending=195588 trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:37:35 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:35.620] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed="1.796µs"   processed=793520219 pending=196024 trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
Jan 09 04:37:38 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:38.353] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.077ms     number=11618484 hash="a2970a…50887a" age=1m29s
Jan 09 04:37:38 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:38.582] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0    itemSize=184.37KiB throttle=356
Jan 09 04:37:44 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:44.862] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.148ms     number=11618485 hash="8eb0a3…503ab8" age=1m30s
Jan 09 04:37:48 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:48.141] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=4.228ms     number=11618486 hash="81893e…1c86a7" age=1m25s
Jan 09 04:37:50 ethnuc1 geth[917]: INFO [01-09|04:37:50.850] Imported new state entries               count=266  elapsed="1.499µs"   processed=793520485 pending=196333 trieretry=122  coderetry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=12984
```

Answer (score 0):

use `--syncmode fast` to do a quicker sync

Comment: Can I use that mode if I'm trying to run an ETH2 validator?

Comment: Can I start using that mode now after already being mostly synced?

Comment: According to this, `fast` is the default, so I was already using that: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options